# python selenium can not login to youtube account with cookies

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, cookies, youtube

**WARNING: cookies provided in this thread may already be invalid so you should do it with your own or some another cookies**

I need to log in to my youtube account using ***cookies and selenium***.

I can send a request to https://www.youtube.com/ with cookies and it will **succeed**:

to know if your request succeeds you should push ctrl+f and type **topbarMenuButtonRenderer**, it will be 2 results if you are logged in to the account and only 1 if you are not

[image: login to youtube via postman]

so the **account is valid** and you can log in to it with cookies, so now let's try to **log in via selenium**:

```
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')
driver.delete_all_cookies()

cookies_list = [{'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': 'YSC', 'value': 'a38PFuRxAE'},
                {'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': 'LOGIN_INFO',
                 'value': 'AFmmF2swRgIhAJrDBvelBtBPZeLLcvN5NdPjNC91wU4dwlXwLxGgLrwiAiEAiqfySzpzR-oQCHMjMwSrRTYX06SPyTTXVq7aknsa9m0:QUQ3MjNmd2xTMWtDckdmYUxWZ2wxLUhzemhua1VOanBqZGlMUzJoMnBVU1NHSnRwcE9EXzBfdnFLa1hhXzBWd3VGVmpiYktpVmVuTjhFd0NXUUN6ZVdMcUFXX281T1RjQTE2d2FaU0Y0OE1pT2pwbmtRTDM2VkhrM1RTM1F5ZjNCWEU1UWJSWnN0OVl2Nnh3WkV6NlRaMkQ5bkZ2NDlSZUh'},
                {'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': '__Secure-3PAPISID',
                 'value': 'Xu1s1vs4Mgl1xUEs/AVuFyeQXwPAFFeQY'},
                {'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': '__Secure-3PSID'},
                {'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': 'wide', 'value': ''},
                {'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': 'VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE', 'value': 'FI45r6mrQr'},
                {'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': 'PREF', 'value': 'tz=Africa.Casablanc'},
                {'domain': 'youtube.com', 'path': '/', 'name': '__Secure-3PSIDCC',
                 'value': 'AEf-XMSrvxDUtrK-9pfKiHiKp-G2KXstszEs3VKc8QNAOQne87VY1Gf5qRFmh30apZ0Y23NVXdx'}]

for cookie in cookies_list:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

print(driver.get_cookies())
```

and **nothing works**, I am not logged in youtube account, I just see this page:
[image: login fail]

as you can see after I added cookies I printed **driver.get_cookies()**, and here is what it *returned*:

```
[{'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__Secure-3PSIDCC', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'AEf-XMSrvxDUtrK-9pfKiHiKp-G2KXstszEs3VKc8QNAOQne87VY1Gf5qRFmh30apZ0Y23NVXdx'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'PREF', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'tz=Africa.Casablanc'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'VISITOR_INFO1_LIVE', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'FI45r6mrQr'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__Secure-3PSID', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'OwgduM77qro_1Obb2aOFY-SUCodOe-WbFGBjwBesoFqHgxebvyLaYFcsEyPQlLwd1Prm1w'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'wide', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': ''},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__Secure-3PAPISID', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'Xu1s1vs4Mgl1xUEs/AVuFyeQXwPAFFeQY'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'LOGIN_INFO', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'AFmmF2swRgIhAJrDBvelBtBPZeLLcvN5NdPjNC91wU4dwlXwLxGgLrwiAiEAiqfySzpzR-oQCHMjMwSrRTYX06SPyTTXVq7aknsa9m0:QUQ3MjNmd2xTMWtDckdmYUxWZ2wxLUhzemhua1VOanBqZGlMUzJoMnBVU1NHSnRwcE9EXzBfdnFLa1hhXzBWd3VGVmpiYktpVmVuTjhFd0NXUUN6ZVdMcUFXX281T1RjQTE2d2FaU0Y0OE1pT2pwbmtRTDM2VkhrM1RTM1F5ZjNCWEU1UWJSWnN0OVl2Nnh3WkV6NlRaMkQ5bkZ2NDlSZUh'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'YSC', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': 'a38PFuRxAE'}]
```

they are exactly the same as the ones I used above however, if I **add this code**:

```
driver.refresh()
print(driver.get_cookies())
```

what I see is:

```
[{'domain': '.youtube.com', 'expiry': 1699659768, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'CONSENT', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'PENDING+879'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'expiry': 1699227767, 'httpOnly': True, 'name': '__Secure-YEC', 'path': '/',
  'sameSite': 'Lax', 'secure': True, 'value': 'CgtFOHBmRnprNldvRSjyz_2ZBg%3D%3D'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'expiry': 1699659769, 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'PREF', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'tz=Europe.London&f4=4000000'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__Secure-3PSIDCC', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'AEf-XMSrvxDUtrK-9pfKiHiKp-G2KXstszEs3VKc8QNAOQne87VY1Gf5qRFmh30apZ0Y23NVXdx'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__Secure-3PSID', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'OwgduM77qro_1Obb2aOFY-SUCodOe-WbFGBjwBesoFqHgxebvyLaYFcsEyPQlLwd1Prm1w'},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': 'wide', 'path': '/', 'secure': True, 'value': ''},
 {'domain': '.youtube.com', 'httpOnly': False, 'name': '__Secure-3PAPISID', 'path': '/', 'secure': True,
  'value': 'Xu1s1vs4Mgl1xUEs/AVuFyeQXwPAFFeQY'}]
```

and it is **not the same** as it was so as I understand youtube assigned me other cookies, but why youtube did it?

when I use the [**cookie quick manager extension**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-GB/firefox/addon/cookie-quick-manager/) ([source code](https://github.com/ysard/cookie-quick-manager/)) in firefox everything **works fine** and I can log in youtube account

*so how can I log into my youtube account with cookies using selenium and what is the reason I can not add cookies? I tried selenium-wire and default selenium and got the same problem*

If I try to log in manually via selenium browser I see this:

What is the problem? **I passed all tests** on https://bot.sannysoft.com/ and **selenium's result is even better than mine** - https://i.imgur.com/1MfSu9L.mp4
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you can do:

**In order to use seleniumwire you have to add the certificate to your browser.** https://github.com/wkeeling/selenium-wire#certificates

1. Login with your email account.

```py
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
import time
import pickle


if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = {}
    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)
    wait = WebDriverWait(browser, 10)
    browser.get('https://gmail.com')
    wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierId"]'))).send_keys('EMAIL')
    wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="identifierNext"]/div/button'))).click()
    time.sleep(5)
    wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="password"]/div[1]/div/div[1]/input'))).send_keys('PASSWORD')
    wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="passwordNext"]/div/button'))).click()

    time.sleep(50)
    browser.get('https://www.youtube.com')
    pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies(), open('test_cookies.pkl', 'wb'))
    print('Dumped Successfully')

    time.sleep(10)
    browser.close()
```

2. Now you have cookies stored, use them.

```py
from seleniumwire.undetected_chromedriver.v2 import Chrome, ChromeOptions
import time
import pickle
if __name__ == "__main__":
    options = {}
    chrome_options = ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('--user-data-dir=hash')
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--incognito")
    chrome_options.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
    # chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
    browser = Chrome(seleniumwire_options=options, options=chrome_options)
    browser.get('https://www.youtube.com')
    time.sleep(10)
    with open('test_cookies.pkl', 'rb') as f:
        cookies = pickle.loads(f.read())
        print(cookies)

    for cookie in cookies:
        browser.add_cookie({'name': cookie['name'], 'value': cookie['value']})

    browser.refresh()
    time.sleep(50)
    browser.close()
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbTn9.jpg

Answer (score 3):

Try resort into using undetected_chromedriver: https://pypi.org/project/undetected-chromedriver/

Comment: got same problem