# How to login in to Google with Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, undetected-chromedriver

Im trying to log in Google with Selenium. Everything work fine except `wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'identifier'))).send_keys(login) wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password'))).send_keys(password)`

By `...send_keys(login)` program pull `login` correctly but not clicking "next" button.
If I click it manually, `...send_keys(pasword)` not sending pre-saved password to the input field.

Please can you tell me how can I fix it?

```
#credentials 
with open('creds.json', 'r') as json_file:
    json_load = json.load(json_file)
#print(json_load['password'])
password = json_load['password'],
login = json_load['login']

#def delay(n):
#    time.sleep(randint(2, n))

#driver = uc.Chrome(use_subprocess=True)
driver = uc.Chrome()
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
driver.get('https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin')  


wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'identifier'))).send_keys(login)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.NAME, 'password'))).send_keys(password)
```

Im trying login into google. by

Comment: you can follow my answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74458816/8449770